# How do I align multiple pattern brushes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, brush

I'm not sure if I've found a bug or if I'm missing something so I figured I'd ask here first.

I'm using Illustrator CC on Windows. My goal is to create multiple pattern brushes that align on a path, allowing me to switch from one pattern to the next without the pattern shifting on the path. Not a shift along the path but offset from it. For example if multiple paths are horizontally drawn and aligned vertically then all of the patterns would line up vertically (none higher or lower than the others).

[image: Screenshot of Pattern Brush Alignment Issue]

I've created each of my pattern brushes with the grey square elements in the image above. The resulting paths are the blue lines below. As can be seen, the third pattern is shifted much lower along the path and doesn't match up with the other two and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I'm using invisible boxes to try and ensure that the dark central stroke is centered along the path.

I've also noticed that the brushes panel for the third stroke has done something odd with the corner treatment. Maybe this has something to do with it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can glean nothing wrong with construction from your screen shot. It all should work as you expect, assuming the hollow box for the problem pattern is *behind* all other artwork, and you haven't adjusted stroke alignments.

Comment: @Scott: I just double checked your points and everything checks out. The hollow box is behind the other artwork and the stroke alignment is the same as the other patterns I've created. Thank you for the feedback and ideas as to what could be causing the issue!

Comment: Not really. I'd have to set up something similar to see if it is indeed a bug. I don't have the time for that at the moment. My only other thought was the corner piece... perhaps that's being used for placement? So add a corner to the one missing it and see if it corrects.... just an idea.

Comment: After tinkering around a little more I've found a solution. I extended the hollow box for the third pattern to encompass the entire square shape instead of the upper third as I had it built and that fixed it. Honestly not entirely sure why since the second pattern is built where hollow box is only in the lower third. Thoughts?

Comment: Oh, I thought it did cover the entire shape (can't tell I guess from the screenshot)... that hollow rectangle should always act as a container for *everything* (visible or not). It defines the size of the brush.

Answer (score 1):

The issue came down to how the pattern was built.

The hollow box was created to fill the space above the third pattern when it should have instead been built to surround and contain all of the elements along with the empty space. Once built correctly, the pattern shifting problem was resolved.